# google plus authentication for web

Tags: javascript, json, google-plus

I want google plus authentication for my web application, when user login via google plus authentication it return user's email.

I do following code for that, It login successfully but It did not return email.

```
<span id="signinButton">
 <span
  class="g-signin"
  data-callback="signinCallback"
  data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email">
 </span>
</span>
```

result in JSON is:

```
{
  "state": "",
  "access_token": "***",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "code": "***",
  "scope": "https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/plus.login https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/userinfo.email",
  "id_token": "*****",
  "authuser": "0",
  "num_sessions": "1",
  "session_state": "***",
  "prompt": "none",
  "client_id": "*******",
  "g_user_cookie_policy": "single_host_origin",
  "cookie_policy": "single_host_origin",
  "response_type": "***",
  "issued_at": "140182",
  "expires_at": "1014176",
  "g-oauth-window": {

  },
  "status": {
    "google_logged_in": true,
    "signed_in": true,
    "method": "PROMPT"
  }
}
```

what should I do for get email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `data-scope` to:

```
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
```

Read more on:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address